# How to append divs on click using jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to append divs again and again inside my container if `Add` is clicked. This code  is adding only one div then it doesn't append new div.

html

```
   <div id="mydiv">
     <div class="col-8 form-group"><label for="">Date</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="date" />
    <p class="add"> Add</strong></p>
    </div>
   </div>
```

jquery

```
 $(".add").on("click", function() {
       $('#mydiv').append(` <div class="col-8 form-group"><label for="">Date</label>
                          <input class="form-control" type="date" />
                         <p class="add"> Add</strong></p>
                        </div>`)
    });
```

Comment: where is mydiv in your html example where you want to append more div ?

Comment: @AmitVerma qyestion updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When need to trigger action on dynamic added html, You need to use **on()** `$(document).on('click','.add',function() {`

```js
$(document).on('click','.add',function() {

    var isValid = true;
    $("input").each(function() {
       var element = $(this);
       if (element.val() == "") {
           isValid = false;
       }
    });
    if(isValid){
        $('#mydiv').append(` <div class="col-8 form-group"><label for="">Date</label>
                          <input class="form-control" type="date" />
                         <p class="add"> Add</strong></p>
                        </div>`);
    }
       
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv">
     <div class="col-8 form-group"><label for="">Date</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="date" name="date" />
    <p class="add"> Add</strong></p>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: I want to add little change can you help on this ? I want to add required on the input and only if user input value of date then new div would be added like this on click `Add`

Comment: yes, just need to check value of latest date

Comment: @D_P check the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you're adding new `add` class links to the document after it has initially loaded, but because you've only targeted the *first* `add` in your code jQuery isn't listening to them.

You need to use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to place the listener on a parent element that then captures to the events that bubble up the DOM.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.add', function() {
  $('#mydiv').append('<div><label>Date</label><input type="date" /><p class="add">Add</strong></p></div>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><label>Date</label>
  <input type="date" />
  <p class="add">Add</strong>
  </p>
</div>
<div id="mydiv"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is your dynamically added elements are not having the event listener.
You can use the below code, which is similar to yours. When you add a new element, add an `eventListener` to the last element selected by the selector `.add`. This ensures that every new element has the `evenListener`.

```
let callFunction =()=>{
       $('#mydiv').append(` <div class="col-8 form-group"><label for="">Date</label>
<input class="form-control" type="date" />
<p class="add"> Add</strong></p>
</div>`);  
}

$(".add").on("click", function() {
 callFunction();   
 $(".add").last().on("click",function(){
   callFunction();
 });
});
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/tusharshahi/pen/vYmmrao)